# Angular 1.2.9 compile error when renderding FB canvas app inside Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, facebook-canvas, angularjs-compile

I've encountered a problem rendering Facebook canvas app on chrome - the app works fine in Firefox or outside of Facebook. The content is rendered using angular.js (1.2.9) which crashes while compiling the DOM.

This problem only occurs on the first request to the canvas app - if the page is reloaded (soft reload), everything works. I believe that for some reason angular starts compiling nodes while the page is still loading (stack trace and breakpoint images attached - https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSozv.jpg). Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: The problem was with href instead of ng-href.